# jquery datatables, custom sorting on server side

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, laravel-4.2

I am using Laravel 4.2, with server side jQuery data-tables.

Package: https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable

How can I add custom sorting ?

like for columns of currency, time, etc

Comment: How about using something like this instead https://github.com/lazymofo/datagrid, or extend it with this https://github.com/ais-one/datagrid_ext

Comment: @AaronGong There are other options available but I have integrated datatables on several pages and I don't want rewrite.

Comment: ok, good luck then, I was looking at datatables too and a few other similar crud stuff, ended up with lazymofo datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: this did not make use of the Chumper/Datatable package, but it does use jQuery datatables so may be of some use.

Here is how I did it. This was a scenario in which I had a table with American football teams in it. Each team was a member of a Conference, that was part of a Division. The teams could be sorted by team name, conference, or division. Below is the server-side code used to implement this. Furthermore, they could be filtered by conference or division.

```
/*
 * Route::get( 'api/v1/teams-table', 'APIController@teamsTable' );
 */
public function dataTable() {
    // get the input parameters
    $i = Input::all();

    // parse the parameters and set default values
    $draw   = isset( $i[ 'draw'   ] ) ? $i[ 'draw'   ] : 1;
    $start  = isset( $i[ 'start'  ] ) ? $i[ 'start'  ] : 0;
    $length = isset( $i[ 'length' ] ) ? $i[ 'length' ] : 10;
    $search = isset( $i[ 'search' ][ 'value' ] ) && '' != $i[ 'search' ][ 'value' ] ? $i[ 'search' ][ 'value' ] : false;
    $ordrby = isset( $i[ 'order'  ] ) ? $i[ 'columns' ][ $i[ 'order' ][ 0 ][ 'column' ] ][ 'name' ] : '';
    $ordrdr = isset( $i[ 'order'  ] ) ? $i[ 'order' ][ 0 ][ 'dir' ] : 'asc';
    $total  = Team::count();
    $filter = $total;


    // get the data
    if ( '' == $search ) {
        switch( $ordrby ) {
            case 'name':
                $teams = Team::with( 'conferences', 'logo', 'conferences.division' )
                    ->skip( $start )
                    ->take( $length )
                    ->orderBy( 'name', $ordrdr )
                    ->get();
                break;
            case 'conference':
                $teams = Team::with( 'conferences', 'logo', 'conferences.division' )
                    ->join( 'conference_team', 'conference_team.team_id', '=', 'teams.id' )->join( 'conferences', 'conferences.id', '=', 'conference_team.conference_id' )
                    ->orderBy( 'conferences.abbr', $ordrdr )
                    ->skip( $start )
                    ->take( $length )
                    ->get();
                break;
            case 'division':
                $teams = Team::with( 'conferences', 'logo', 'conferences.division' )
                    ->skip( $start )
                    ->take( $length )
                    ->conference()
                    ->division()
                    ->orderBy( 'abbr', $ordrdr )
                    ->get();
                break;
            default:
                $teams = Team::with([ 'conferences', 'logo', 'conferences.division' ])
                    ->skip( $start )
                    ->take( $length )
                    ->get();
        }
    } else {
        $teams = Team::with( 'conferences', 'logo', 'conferences.division' )
            ->skip( $start )
            ->take( $length )
            ->where( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
            ->orWhereHas( 'conferences', function( $q ) use ( $search ) { 
                $q->where( 'abbr', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
                    ->orWhereHas( 'division', function( $qu ) use ( $search ) {
                        $qu->where( 'abbr', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' );
                    }); 
            })
            ->get();
        $filter = Team::with( 'conferences', 'logo', 'conferences.division' )
            ->where( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
            ->orWhereHas( 'conferences', function( $q ) use ( $search ) { 
                $q->where( 'abbr', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
                    ->orWhereHas( 'division', function( $qu ) use ( $search ) {
                        $qu->where( 'abbr', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' );
                    }); 
            })
            ->count();
    }

    // loop through the retrieved data and format it to be returned as JSON
    $data = [];
    foreach ( $teams as $t ) {
        $show = URL::route( 'admin.team.show', $t->slug );
        $edit = URL::route( 'admin.team.depth_chart', $t->slug );
        $data[] = [
            'checkbox'   => '<label><input type="checkbox" class="ace" value="' . $t->id . '" /><span class="lbl"></span></label>',
            'logo'       => '<img src="' . $t->logo->filename . '" alt="' . $t->name . ' logo" height="40">',
            'name'       => [
                'display' => link_to_route( 'admin.team.show', $t->name, [ $t->slug ] ),
                'filter'  => $t->name,
                'sort'    => $t->name,
            ],
            'conference' => [
                'display' => link_to_route( 'admin.conference.show', $t->conferences[ 0 ]->abbr, [ $t->conferences[ 0 ]->slug ] ),
                'filter'  => $t->conferences[ 0 ]->name . ' ' . $t->conferences[ 0 ]->abbr,
                'sort'    => $t->conferences[ 0 ]->abbr,
            ],
            'division'   => [
                'display' => link_to_route( 'admin.division.show', $t->conferences[ 0 ]->division->abbr, [ $t->conferences[ 0 ]->division->slug ] ),
                'filter'  => $t->conferences[ 0 ]->division->name . ' ' . $t->conferences[ 0 ]->division->abbr,
                'sort'    => $t->conferences[ 0 ]->division->abbr,
            ],
            'site'       => '<a target="_blank" href="' . $t->url . '">website <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>',
            'actions'    => sprintf( $this->actions, $show, $edit, $show, $edit ),
        ];
    }

    $tdata = [
        'draw'            => $draw,
        'recordsTotal'    => $total,  //consider caching or setting fixed value for this
        'recordsFiltered' => $filter,
        'data'            => $data,
    ];

    return Response::json( $tdata );
}
```

With any luck, you can adjust this example to fit your situation. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do it

n.b. it's not optimized. more or less a complete code snippet without error checking

laravel controller function (it's L5.2 but easily downgrade-able to 4.2):

```
    $response = array();
    $query = MyModel::query();

    $response['recordsTotal'] = MyModel::count();
    $response['draw'] = Input::get('draw', 0);

    $query->where('searchField', 'LIKE', '%' . Input::get('search', array('value' => ''))['value'] . '%');
    $response['recordsFiltered'] = $query->count();

    $query->take(Input::get('length', 1));
    $query->offset(Input::get('start', 0));


    $columns = Input::get('columns');
    $orders = Input::get('order', []);

    $data = $data->toArray();
    foreach($orders as $order){
        $idx = $order['column'];
        $column = $columns[$idx];

        $orderFactor = 1;
        if($order['dir'] == 'desc')
            $orderFactor = -1;
        $dname = $column['data'];
        if(count($data)>0){
            if(isset($data[0][$dname])){
                usort($data, function($record1, $record2) use($dname, $orderFactor){
                    // here you implement your custom sorting
                    // like if($dname === 'price') return compare_price($record1[$dname], $record2[$dname]) * $orderFactor; 
                    // but I hope you're not storing prices as strings in your database. you won't need this custom sorting
                    //
                    return strcmp($record1[$dname], $record2[$dname]) * $orderFactor;
                });
            }
        }
    }
    $response['data'] = $data;
    return Response::json($response);
```

p.s. this code assumes that the 'data' field of the datatable columns is named exactly as the field name in your database.
You will also need to use a render_function to render the datatable column as you wish

datatable columns:

```
columns: [
    { data: 'price', orderable: true, searchable: true, render: render_price },
    { data: 'anotherField' },
    [...]
],
```

render_function example:

```
    function render_price(price, type, row) {
        return price + ' USD';
    }
```

this way you will have your datatable displaying columns the way you want (e.g. price = 10.50$)

and they will be sortable

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sort the collection or query result in any order, you can do something like this:

```
$orders = Order::all()->SortBy('currency','desc');
```

or

```
$customers = Customers::where('age',$age)->orderBy('currency','desc')->get();
```

By the way, why are you still on Laravel 4 when there is Laravel 8 already?

Comment: "By the way, why are you still on Laravel 4 when there is Laravel 8 already?" because this is a 6 year old question?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if by `custom sorting` you mean sorting the rows by clicking on the headers? If that is what you mean then you can define them on the client side by defining the datatable settings.

```
oSettings = $("#{{$table->getId()}}").dataTable().fnSettings();
oSettings.aaSorting = [[6, 'desc']];
```

But if you want to maintain a default sorting of a particular column when the datatable loads, then

```
Datatable::table()
        ->addColumn($theader)       // these are the column headings to be shown
        ->setOptions('order', array([$ordercolumn ,"desc"]))
        ->setUrl(route('route.name', $form_id))   
        ->render()
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

Haven't you checked the documentation? Because it's explained there:

```
public function getDatatable() { return Datatable::collection(User::all(array('id','name'))) ->showColumns('id', 'name') ->searchColumns('name') ->orderColumns('id','name') ->make(); }
```

Comment: I am asking about custom sorting, not column order or anything else. Where is custom sorting in your answer, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean with custom sorting? Please give a better explanation or example.

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/currency - that is for client end JS solution, I am looking same on server side.